# Codename one - get value from text area using GUI(codename one designer) while coding using java coding on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7, codenameone

For some reason I can't fetch value from a Text area called "txtNum1" and "txtNum2", am using "txtNum1.getText()" & "txtNum2.getText()" it can't even recognize "txtNum1" I used the GUI builder. Am I doing something wrong?

```
protected void onMain_BtnAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    String num1 = txtNum1.getText();
    String num2 = txtNum2.getText();
    calc(Integer.parseInt(num1),Integer.parseInt(num2));


}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you have provided. How you are knowing that the name of `Text area` variable is `txtNum1`?

Comment: I named both Text areas to "txtNum1" and "txtNum2" in the Codename one designer. This is under the properties on the name.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
String num1 = findTextNum1(c).getText();
```