# Variable names assigned to input/output objects in codename one designer are not being recognised in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7, codenameone

After building an interface using codename one's designer, I started coding into NetBeans and it is highlighting showing an error on all the variable names I gave the input objects I created with the designer. What could I be doing wrong? "NumOne" and "NumTwo" are the names I assigned to the text fields on the designer. NetBeans keeps saying they are undefined variables  Here is my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onMain_BtnAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    String num1 = NumOne.getText();
    String num2 = NumTwo.getText();
    calc(num1,num2);


}
```

Comment: "Undefined" in this case could mean inaccessible, or misspelled, or any number of things.  Please show us more code so we can see what the issue is.  Where do you declare those variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codename one - get value from text area using GUI(codename one designer) while coding using java coding on NetBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940663/codename-one-get-value-from-text-area-using-guicodename-one-designer-while-c)